# XSD 0-unlimited nodes in any order

Tags: powershell, xsd

Is it possible with XSD to allow a limited set of child nodes names, but allow 0-unlimited instances of each, in any order?

So far as I can tell `ns:any` allows any order, but no more than one instance of each, `ns:sequence` requires the specified order while `ns:choice` limits you to only one of the list.

But I also seemingly can't just have a `ns:simpleType` or `ns:complexType` with no order indicator.

Alternatively, I could import my XML without validating against an XSD, then validate each of those required nodes against their own XSD, but I can't seem to find a way to validate an `[Xml.Element]` directly. Perhaps I could take each of the nodes and create a temporary `[Xml.Document]` from it to validate, but as far as I can tell the only way to validate XML against an XSD is when reading from a file, and writing a temporary file hundreds to thousands of times just to validate a node seems horribly inefficient.

I have spent more than a little time developing my XSD, so I hope there is an XSD based solution. But at least all this work has resulted in much more consistent XML than I would have otherwise had, and the XSD exercise provides a specification of sorts for the code I need to validate the XML. Some consolation there.

EDIT: The potential solution I have found is to make an `ns:group`, that contains an `ns:choice` that contains all the child nodes as `minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'`, then reference that group where those nodes are needed with `<xs:group ref="TaskGroup" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>`. Still not ideal as another subtlety is in two places I need JUST the tasks (of which there are maybe 30) and in one other location I also need to allow for a node called `<package>` that can be interspersed with the other task nodes. At which point I have two groups where the vast majority is the same 30 tasks and the only difference is one also has a `<package>`. And there seems to be no way to use `ns:group`, `ns:union` and `ns:choice` together to get the required result. Damn you Microsoft!

Ugly, and I may still just abandon XSD and code my own validation.

EDIT: I did try using an `ns:extension` like this, and I get an error that `The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:extension' element is not supported in this context.`

```
    <xs:complexType name='TaskList'>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name='taskCopy' type='Task_Copy' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskCreateFolder' type='Task_CreateFolder' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskDelete' type='Task_Delete' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            
            <xs:element name='taskExecuteProgram' type='Task_ExecuteProgram' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskInstallProgram' type='Task_InstallProgram' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            
            <xs:element name='taskInventoryHardware' type='Task_InventoryHardware' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
            <xs:element name='taskInventorySoftware' type='Task_InventorySoftware' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
            
            <xs:element name='taskManageAsset' type='Task_ManageAsset' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskManageNetworkLocation' type='Task_ManageNetworkLocation' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskManageManageMappedDrive' type='Task_ManageManageMappedDrive' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskManageZipFile' type='Task_ManageZipFile' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            
            <xs:element name='taskMirror' type='Task_Mirror' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            <xs:element name='taskSetRegistryValue' type='Task_SetRegistryValue' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name='PackageList'>
        <xs:extension base="TaskList">
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name='package' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexType>
```

So, it seems to me that, in XSD 1.0 at least, `ns:choice` is very limited and cannot be unioned or extended.

EDIT2: To clarify, this is a simplified example of what my XML looks like.

```
<packages>
    <package id="ParentPackage">
        <taskCopy id="SimpleTask">
            <process>
                <source>PATH TO... source</source>
                <destination>PATH TO... destination</destination>
            </process>
        </taskCopy>
        <package>NestedPackage</package>
        <taskCopy id="ComplexTask">
            <preprocess>
                <taskDelete>
                    <process>
                        <path>[Product~Journals]\*</path>
                    </process>
                </taskDelete>
            </preprocess>
            <process>
                <source>PATH TO... source</source>
                <destination>PATH TO... destination</destination>
            </process>
        </taskCopy>
    </package>
    <package id="NestedPackage">
        <taskCopy id="AnotherSimpleTask">
            <process>
                <source>PATH TO... source</source>
                <destination>PATH TO... destination</destination>
            </process>
        </taskCopy>
    </package>
</packages>
```

There are 30 different Task options, and any of them can occur nested within the `<preprocess>` node of a Task. They can also occur in a `<package>`, but a package can also contain another nested `<package>`, which itself contains tasks and packages. Order is variable for both tasks and packages.

The goal is to not need to maintain duplicate task lists to handle the difference between what can be in a package node and what can be in a task preprocess node.

Answer (score 0):

Define a complex type that contains a choice with all the optional childs and assign that complex type to the parent of all the childs.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Root" type="randomType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="randomType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="a"/>
            <xs:element name="b"/>
            <xs:element name="c"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

an xml like this is then still valid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b>a</b>
    <a>text</a>
    <b>a</b>
    <b>a</b>
    <b>a</b>
    <b>a</b>
    <b>a</b>
    <a>text</a>
</Root>
```

Comment: The key is, I have a big `ns:choice`, that I could call a-z, then I have another `ns:choice` that I could call 1-3, and I have two locations that would use a-z and a third that needs a-z AND 1-3. It's that union of two `ns:choice` that I seem not to be able to do. It seems I need to maintain two copies of a-z, one with 1-3 also defined and one without. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: can you add an example of the xml that you want to describe with the xsd. from the text i cannot fully understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I revised the original post with some example XML. Hopefully it makes sense.